# List of books and article I studied on resume?

Tags: resume

I graduated from university. I read mathematics as my major subject and theoretical physics and computer science for my minor subjects. I tried to get a graduate student place but was not successful. Now I am trying to find a job.

Is it wise to include in my CV the list of books and articles that I have studied to show my skills? Is it worth it to say how many exercises I did from each book?

Comment: Nope, most people won't care about the stuff that's you've studied, as it's difficult to qualify what you have actually done and what you have taken in. Now if you had an exam or some mark showing how well you did, that would be different.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it wise to include in my CV the list of books and articles that I
>   have studied to show my skills? Is it worth it to say how many
>   exercises I did from each book?

**No.**

Be ready to talk about books that have most impacted your studies. Be ready to talk about which you liked, which you didn't, and why it will help you be better at your profession. Be ready to talk about what you learned from your studies and readings, should it come up during an interview.

But listing on your resume "the books and articles I have read" and "how many exercises I completed", won't show much maturity. Leave that off.

Answer (score 1):

I would also say no,

I never read a CV with this kind of list and i would never read one,
the main reason is that someone which is reading your CV usually, does not know these school book, and i'm sure, that he will not google for the titles.

A resume must be Interesting and fast to read, this kind of details are not important.